# How to send request to the server on refresh page in `beforeunload` event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I want to send the current state value, `currentPositionSec` to the server, when page refreshed.
Since `componentWillUnmount` won't be called on a refresh of the page, I used `beforeunload` event.

```
  componentDidMount () {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnload)
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnload)
  }

  onUnload (e) {
    console.log('INSIDE onUnload')
    const { hashedId } = this.props
    const { currentPositionSec } = this.state
    // sends the progress to a server
    emitter.emit(LECTURE_VIDEO_PROGRESS, {
      currentPositionSeconds: currentPositionSec,
      hashedId: hashedId
    })
  }
```

`INSIDE onUnload` is printed for a short period of time and the page refreshes, I tried this many times and the progress is only saved once, which is weird. Can we wait the code inside `onUnload` to execute? when I add this in `onUnload` method, the progress will be saved, but I don't want the popup to be displayed.

```
e.preventDefault();
e.returnValue = '';
```

Comment: What does emitter.emit do? I tried a `fetch` before unload and it works every single time (you can preserve log in  network tab of devtools).

Comment: @HMR it has many nested calls there, can you send me the link for the `fetch`?

Comment: It emits the data to be saved in the server, to the hight level component.

Comment: So in Chrome devtools under network you can see activity and you don't see that when you refresh and have `Preserve log` checked?

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-comment-c497c?file=/index.js) is a sandbox and [here](https://c497c.csb.app/) you can open the app. Are you using setTimeout in emitter.emit?

Comment: @HMR I think It relates with this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457535/why-in-chrome-in-onunload-and-onbeforeunload-is-my-xmlhttprequest-being-cancell.